# using jq I want to output json object within a json object including the keys not just the value

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have this stored as a file:

```json
{
  "Targets": [
    {
      "Id": "xxx_hourly_cron",
      "Arn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:000000000000:cluster/drupal-cluster",
      "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/ecsEventsRole",
      "EcsParameters": {
        "TaskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:000000000000:task-definition/xxx-cron:55",
        "TaskCount": 1,
        "EnableECSManagedTags": false,
        "EnableExecuteCommand": false,
        "PropagateTags": "TASK_DEFINITION"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using bash and jq I want to trim it down this this:

```json
{
  "TaskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:000000000000:task-definition/xxx-cron:55",
  "TaskCount": 1,
  "EnableECSManagedTags": false,
  "EnableExecuteCommand": false,
  "PropagateTags": "TASK_DEFINITION"
}
```

I have tried this but it does not output the keys:

`cat rule-target.json | jq '(.Targets[] .EcsParameters[])'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are so close:

```
$ jq '.Targets[].EcsParameters' rule-target.json 
{
  "TaskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:000000000000:task-definition/xxx-cron:55",
  "TaskCount": 1,
  "EnableECSManagedTags": false,
  "EnableExecuteCommand": false,
  "PropagateTags": "TASK_DEFINITION"
}
```

As `EcsParameters` isn't an array, you shouldn't unwrap it (`[]`).

Usually it's a useless use of `cat` when doing `cat file | cmd`, many commands takes files as arguments:

```
cmd -flag -flag2 file1.txt file2.txt
```

and if they don't then you can redirect stdin:

```
cmd -flag -flag2 < file1.txt
```

Comment: So many jq experts now. Your answer is optimal. Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
jq '(.Targets[]|.EcsParameters)' rule-target.json
```

Which results in:

```
{
  "TaskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:000000000000:task-definition/xxx-cron:55",
  "TaskCount": 1,
  "EnableECSManagedTags": false,
  "EnableExecuteCommand": false,
  "PropagateTags": "TASK_DEFINITION"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
jq '.Targets[] | .EcsParameters' rule-target.json
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/H7SPEJxzCO)</kbd>

array wrappers seen in the current case remove the object wrappers